# shell script to check if program should be running and restart it if appropriate

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following script

```
#!/bin/sh
if [cat stream_should_be_running.txt == 'true']; then #file will either contain true or false
    if [ps ax|grep -v grep|grep tracker_stream]; then # check if stream is currently running
        exit 0
    else
        /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/dashboard/fbadmin/manage.py tracker_stream; # restart stream
        exit 0
else
    exit 0
fi
```

This script should check if a daemon script is suppose to be running. If it is suppose to be running then it checks to see if the script is running and restarts it if it isn't.  Currently I get `syntax error: unexpected end of file` when I try to running the file manually.

So two questions:

1. why am i pulling the syntax error
2. outside of this should this script run properly?

Thanks

---

EDIT:
here is an updated version of the script and a few notes:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -vx; # turn on shell debugging

if [[ "$(cat stream_should_be_running.txt)" == "true" ]]; then
    if [ ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -q tracker_stream ]; then
        exit 0
    else
        /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/dashboard/fbadmin/manage.py tracker_stream;
        exit 0
    fi
else
    exit 0
fi
```

to note:

- vim marks `$(...)` as a syntax error ( i don't know if that matters)
- `ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -q tracker_stream` , `ps ax|grep -v grep|grep tracker_stream` , and `cat stream_should_be_running.txt` all execute properly from the command line

---

EDIT 2:
shell debugging gives the error

```
$ sh stream_checker.sh

+ $'\r'
: command not foundline 3: 
if [[ "$(cat stream_should_be_running.txt)" == "true" ]]; then 
    echo 'test';
    if [ ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -q tracker_stream ]; then 
        exit 0
    else
    /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/dashboard/fbadmin/manage.py tracker_stream;
    exit 0
    fi
else
    exit 0
fi
```

stream_checker.sh: line 15: syntax error: unexpected end of file

so the only things that come before where the `+ $'\r'` is returns are `#!/bin/sh` and `set -vx`.

This is running on a linux system. The my local machine is osx lion and the live machine is a linux server on webfaction.

Comment: Why don't you just record the pid in the file instead and do a `kill -0 pid` and verify the return code, zero it's running non-zero it's not running.

Comment: The user can set whether tracker_stream should be running. This action is what changes the value in stream_should_be_running.txt from false to true.  The rest of the script that I've shown just maintains tracker_stream as a daemon when it is active.

Comment: Try running with ./sh -x script.sh

Comment: using `sh -x script.sh` doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: Well, it shouldn't, but what does it show?

Comment: i mean to say that is gives the same syntax error as before

Comment: Yes, of course it gives the same error, but it shows lines of script as they are executed -> it's called script debugging: you should isolate issue to effectively solve it

Comment: Try `if [ "$(cat stream_should_be_running.txt)" = "true" ];` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I think I got it...

I used the '-s' switch in pidof to only get one result.
The '-z' switch means "return true if the string is empty".

```
#!/bin/sh
PID=$(pidof -s tracker_stream);
if [ $(cat stream_should_be_running.txt) = "true"]; then #file will either contain true or false
    if [ -z $PID ]; then # check if stream is currently NOT running
        /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/dashboard/fbadmin/manage.py tracker_stream; # restart stream
        exit 0;
    fi
fi
```

EDIT: From the last note you posted it looks like you might have a Ctrl-M char `(^M)`, somewhere on your file.
It's not merely a `^` followed by a `M`, it's a end of line character.

You could open your file with `vim -b` to check if you see any of those characters.
Then type:

```
:%s/^V^M//g
```

That command reads like "match all (^M) chars and substitute them with void".
In short it will remove all (^M) chars from your file.
The (^V^M) bit means that you have to hit CTRL-V CTRL-M, in order to insert the (^M) char.

2) what exactly do you mean by "outside of this"?

Comment: as to your question. I'm not that familiar with shell scripting and so I am not sure what other parts of this code might throw an error.  My main concern is whether you can use cat to return true or false from the file and have the if block terminate based on that.

Comment: I have checked and yes, you can do something like: if[ $(cat a.txt) = "true" ];    (And it will return if your file as "false" instead for example)

Comment: You could also just create that file, leave it empty, and just test if the file existed with the '-f' switch: [ -f stream.txt ]       You would need to remove it later though...

Comment: unfortunately pidof does not exist on the unix system I'm running this on. Anyways tracker_stream is a django manage command so using ps is pretty much the only way to look up the pid.

Comment: If you don't have pidof you could use pgrep, though I'm guessing you probably don't have it aswell...

Answer (score 1):

your square brackets need spaces around them, i.e.

```
if [ ps ax|grep -v grep|grep tracker_stream ] ;
```

AND more importantly, you need to use command substitution so your script can get the value inside `stream_should_be_running.txt` using `$( cat ... )`, i.e.

```
if [[ "$(cat stream_should_be_running.txt)" == 'true' ]] ; then 
    #file will either contain true or false
    if[ ps ax|grep -v grep|grep -q tracker_stream ] ; then 
        # check if stream is currently running
        exit 0
    else
        /usr/local/bin/python2.7 ~/webapps/dashboard/fbadmin/manage.py tracker_stream; 
        # restart stream
        exit 0
else
    exit 0
fi
```

Also better to dbl-quote the value returned by `$(cat ...)` in case some how there are spaces in the file.

Finally, turn on shell debugging by adding `set -vx` near top script. Then you can each line/block of code as it being executed, AND the values that are substituted for variables.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, I'm definitely looking for pointers like this, but this doesn't solve the syntax error.

Comment: Doah, missed some crucial stuff in your code, note edits above.

Comment: I have a feeling we are slowly getting closer, but this didn't seem to solve the syntax error

Comment: Note the addition of `-q` to your last grep in the 2nd if. Test that line seperately, if you get error message, remove -q and put `>/dev/null 2>&1` at the end of the line. If turn on `set -vx`, edit your message to show the debugging info just before the error message. Good luck.

Comment: iF you used `set -x`, then we can't see what command was being executed that returned `+ $'\r'`. If you did use `set -vx`, we need to see the line above what you have included. Alson $'\r' indicates a DOS based file, are you on Windows? YOu need a file without the $'\r'. Good luck.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4702/discussion-between-shellter-and-daniel-nill)